# Convert Visual Studio exe-project in lib-project

Tags: visual-studio

I am developing an application (exe) in c++ with visual studio. I am not that experienced. Now, I came to the conclusion that it might be better to compile the general program functionality into an lib or dll file, which I then would use in a different visual studio project, where I basically implement the functions from the lib files for the more specific purpose of my project. With my current setup, I get the impression that I am starting to mix the gerenal functionality with the specific problem statement.

Basically I am asking for a way to convert my current full visual studio project into two separate projects, one for the gerenal lib files representing the classes and program modules, and one for the specific problem implementation. Is it possible to also keep everything in one visual studio project (**edit:** solution) for convenience?

Comment: Well, it's either "two separate projects" or "one Visual Studio project". They are mutually exclusive options. Or did you mean, for the latter, one Visual Studio *solution*?

Comment: Yeah, "solution" is the better word that I was looking for.

Comment: Well, in that case it is both possible and eminently sensible. I think that's the normal approach (but I'm an MFC programmer, so maybe I'm not an expert on what's 'normal').

Comment: You can just "Add a new project" to the solution (from the Solution Explorer window), define it as a "Library" (.lib or .dll, as you prefer); then just move those source files from the original project into to the new one. And add a project dependency from the EXE to the LIB.